# Can I programatically manipulate Lightroom's "rejected" flag in images?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, exiftool

Can I use a tool like `exif2` or `exiftool` to programatically inspect and manipulate the flag used for "Rejected" in Lightroom? I can't find a field that seems to correspond to it. If not, is there another OSX/Linux/Unix tool that could do that?

Comment: Here's a good intro to the LR database http://www.earthboundlight.com/phototips/querying-sqlite-lightroom-database.html
I've tried manipulating the Pick field directly in a test db using SQLite but the photo shows no flag and no flag options when I reopen the catalog so there's more to it than just the pick field.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is Lightroom-specific metadata, stored in the Lightroom catalog. You can verify that with this command¹ in the OS X Terminal:

```
$ exiftool -b -xmp mypic.dng > orig.xmp
```

Now go back to Lightroom, reject `mypic.dng`, and hit <kbd>⌘/Ctrl-S</kbd> to force Lightroom to save its copy of the metadata to the photo file on disk.² Back in the Terminal, say:

```
$ exiftool -b -xmp mypic.dng > new.xmp
$ diff orig.xmp new.xmp
```

That will tell you what changes Lightroom made to the photo's embedded metadata. All you'll see are a metadata date change and some [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) changes. You will not see any mention of a "Rejected in Lightroom" type of field, because there isn't one. There is nothing there for `exiftool` to manipulate.

You'll have to do this in Lua, as a [Lightroom plugin](http://www.adobe.com/content/dotcom/en/devnet/photoshoplightroom.html). Once you have the `LrPhoto` reference, you simply say:

```
photo:getRawMetadata('pickStatus')
```

to get the current value. It will be 1 if picked, 0 if neutral, and -1 if rejected.

You could then un-reject a photo with:

```
photo:setRawMetadata('pickStatus', 0)
```

---

**Footnotes**:

1. If you don't yet have `exiftool` on your system, the easiest way to get it is to first [install Homebrew](http://brew.sh), then say `brew install exiftool`.
2. Even with the [Automatically Write Changes into XMP](http://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/metadata-basics-actions.html) setting enabled, there can be an arbitrarily-long delay between a user action in Lightroom and the XMP update hitting the disk, depending on what else Lightroom has going on.

   I once lost hours of work by changing a core keyword in my catalog, then hours later running `exiftool` on some files to make a change I couldn't make from within Lightroom. After running that command, I said Metadata → Read Metadata from File, then was dismayed to find that those photos' metadata was reset to a state from many hours before because those XMP updates were batched behind the updates for the core keyword change, still running! (It took about a full day for Lightroom to finish updating all the XMP data on disk.)

   If I'd said Metadata → Save Metadata to File before running `exiftool` on those files, I wouldn't have lost that work, because it jumps the queue, saving the metadata for the selected photos immediately, even if there are prior metadata changes still being saved in the background.