# Lightroom: can you export the 'picked' flag to another software? Alternatively, can you add a keyword based on the picked flag?

Tags: lightroom, keywords, lightroom-6

I use Lightroom 6 on Windows 10.
I am considering switching to another software; I know there are programs (eg Acdsee) that can import keywords and library data from Lightroom, but I have not found any that can import the picked flags.

- **Do you know of a way/a Windows software to export the picked flag from Lightroom to another software (eg Acdsee, Aftershot, etc)?** I understand generic recommendations are frowned upon on stackexchange sites, but this is not that - I am not asking what alternatives you recommend, I am asking if you know of any software which performs a very specific task, so it's very much a factual, non-subjective yes or no type of question
- Alternatively, **is there a way to create keywords based on the 'picked' flag? Ie add a keyword like 'picked' to every photo which I have flagged as picked?** I am not sure if Lightroom can do this automatically, if there is a plugin, or if a small script could be put together and made into a plugin. If I can make that into a keyword, I should be able to use the keyword to filter accordingly in the new software

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would [write the Lightroom metadata to sidecar XMP files](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-classic/help/metadata-basics-actions.html) and use those to import all metadata into another non-Adobe application.
Unfortunately pick/reject flags are one of the those things that are stored in the catalog only and are *not* written to XMP<sup>[1](https://feedback.photoshop.com/conversations/lightroom-classic/lightroom-save-flags-in-xmp/5f5f45974b561a3d4255490a),[2](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/40196/9161)</sup>.

Therefore your proposed solution of using keyword seems to be the best option.

To do so, you need to first find all your images with a *picked* flag:

1. Go to the **Library** module
2. In the top, click on *Attribute* in the *Library Filter*:

[image]
3. Press the white flag to show only *picked* photos.

Now you need to assign a keyword of your choice to all these photos:

1. In the **Library** module select all photos that are shown while the *Library Filter* set in the previous steps is active
2. In the *Keywording* panel on the right add the keyword of your choice (I chose *picked* in this example):

[image]

3. While the photos are still selected, make sure that the metadata (i.e. the keyword) is written to the (sidecar XMP) files by going to the menu item *Metadata* → *Save Metadata to Files*

Comment: Do you know if Lightroom can store metadata in xmp files also for DNG photos? I seem to remember reading that, for DNG, all metadata is stored in the DNG itself. PS Arguably a moot point if I export all the edits as TIFFs or high-quality jpg, but still a curiosity

Comment: After I [looked up your question on the internet](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=xmp+lightroom+dng) and [on Photo.SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=xmp+lightroom), I [found](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/69022/9161) [that](https://community.adobe.com/t5/lightroom-classic/is-it-possible-to-use-xmp-files-with-dng/td-p/10784654?page=1) XMP sidecar files are not created for JPEG, TIFF, PSD, and DNG files. Those filetypes store the metadata embedded in the file.
Please, don't make me your search engine input device. I would appreciate if you would show research effort.